# How to manually label a LabelList in Recharts React

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I wanted to manually name the bars in a horizontal bar chart like this

```
<Bar dataKey="performanceavg" fill="#FFB85F">
    <LabelList dataKey="performanceavg" position="insideRight" />
    <LabelList content={"Performance Average"} position="insideLeft" />
</Bar>
```

Tested different variations of this but sadly without success.

I made it to use this 
http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/BarChartWithMinHeight

```
<Bar dataKey="performanceavg" fill="#FFB85F">
    <LabelList dataKey="performanceavg" position="insideRight" />
    <LabelList content={this.renderCustomizedLabel} position="insideLeft" />
</Bar>
```

with

```
renderCustomizedLabel = (props) => {
    console.log(props)
    const { x, y, width, height, value } = props;
    console.log(props)

    return (
        <g>
        <text x={x} y={y + height/2}>Performance Average</text>
        </g>
    );
};
```

but this seems pretty complicated and the y + height/2 isn't the middle but probably needs to work with the font's height somehow. In general this seems complicated for a simple labeling

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Ah like this it works :-)

```
  <Bar dataKey="performanceavg" fill="#FFB85F">
      <LabelList dataKey="performanceavg" position="insideRight" />
      <LabelList position="insideLeft">Performance Average</LabelList>
  </Bar>
```